# Magento 2 How to hide configuration field with a condition?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2

I have the following configuration field:

[image]

I'm using a **backend_model** and **frontend_model** for rendering this field with two options.

How can I disable it with a condition? What should I use?

Comment: Based on other configs field?

Comment: No, custom condition. In my case it is database table entities.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive by using frontend model. try below step

> system.xml

```
<field id="your_field_id" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Cargo Type Mapping</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\CargoFrontend</frontend_model>
    <backend_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\CargoBackend</backend_model>
</field>
```

> Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\CargoFrontend.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

class CargoFrontend extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('tab1',['label' => __('Cargo Type'),  'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('tab2',['label' => __('Attribute Set'),  'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve HTML markup for given form element
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $isCheckboxRequired = $this->_isInheritCheckboxRequired($element);

        // Disable element if value is inherited from other scope. Flag has to be set before the value is rendered.
        if ($element->getInherit() == 1 && $isCheckboxRequired) {
            $element->setDisabled(true);
        }

        $html = '<td class="label"><label for="' .
            $element->getHtmlId() . '"><span' .
            $this->_renderScopeLabel($element) . '>' .
            $element->getLabel() .
            '</span></label></td>';
        $html .= $this->_renderValue($element);

        if ($isCheckboxRequired) {
            $html .= $this->_renderInheritCheckbox($element);
        }

        $html .= $this->_renderHint($element);

        return $this->_decorateRowHtml($element, $html);
    }

    /**
     * Decorate field row html
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element
     * @param string $html
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _decorateRowHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element, $html)
    {
        if(1 == 2){//you can add your condition based on table entities
            $style = 'style="display: none"';
        } else {
            $style = 'style="display: block"';
        }
        return '<tr id="row_' . $element->getHtmlId() . $style .'">' . $html . '</tr>';
    }
}
```

you can add your condition in `_decorateRowHtml` function from frontend model

Comment: condition shouldn't be depend on another field, it should be depend on(in my case) custom database table -> if table is empty

Comment: I have updated please check